# Can 2 functions access an object variable in Python

Tags: python

I understand in Python a class can have a class variable (shared among all objects), and also a unique object variable (which is uniquely assignable from object to object).

However, why do I get a 'object has no attribute 'nObjVar' error, when I try to access that object's variable from another function?

```
class TestClass:
    nClassVar1 = 0                  #Class Var shared across all objects 
    def __init__(self, defaultInitVal = 0):
        nObjVar = defaultInitVal     #Object Var Only

    def MyFuncMult(self):
        result =  nObjVar * 10;
        return ( result )
```

Comment: You need to access `nObjVar` as `self.nObjVar`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because you are defining it as a local variable in the init, if you want it to be a member of the object you need to type

`self.nObjVar`

this will set it to a member

Answer (score 2):

To make a variable available to all methods in a class, save it in the `self` namespace.

```
class TestClass:
    nClassVar1 = 0                  #Class Var shared across all objects 
    def __init__(self, defaultInitVal = 0):
        self.nObjVar = defaultInitVal     #Object Var Only

    def MyFuncMult(self):
        result =  self.nObjVar * 10;
        return ( result )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `self.nObjVar` to reference the variable of the instance.